# Hide the undo button when editing shapes with Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to hide (ie: don't show, because its annoying) the undo button when editing a shape on a v3 Google Map?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try the undocumented `suppressUndo` parameter.

It seems to work fine with google.maps.Circle

```
var c = new google.maps.Circle({
    map: myMap,
    ...
    suppressUndo: true
});
```

related issue in the issue tracker: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4013

Comment: Works on Polygons too :-). I noticed that the `insert_at` event is not fired when a change to a midline point is undone, so I just got rid of the Undo button with this property. And, it is a little visually cluttering anyway.

Comment: hello I know this is old thread but I am trying to add suppressUndo: true to my google.maps.Circle but it is not a known property for that object.

Error 
suppressUndo: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Circle | CircleLiteral | CircleOptions | null | undefined'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'suppressUndo' does not exist in type 'Circle | CircleLiteral | CircleOptions'.

Comment: @kareem.khalil Is this about TypeScript? If yes, then, of course, it's a matter of typings and the official typings don't have this undocumented option in them. You can fix that by adding it via your own global typings, but that's out of scope of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Angular Google map and when I create new object from `google.maps.Circle` or `google.maps.Polygon` the `suppressUndo` gives me error `is not assignable to parameter of type`

so i fixed it as below:

```
 const savedCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
      map: map,
      ....
    });
    
 savedCircle.set('suppressUndo',true );
```

I used **set('suppressUndo',true )** and now it is working